# multiple updates for an array with $push

Tags: node.js, mongodb

consider the following document skeleton

```
{
  _id: "615749dce3438547adfff9bc",
  items: [
    {
      type: "shirt",
      color: "red",
      sizes: [
        {
          label: "medium",
          stock: 10,
          price: 20,
        },
        {
          label: "large",
          stock: 30,
          price: 40,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "shirt",
      color: "green",
      sizes: [
        {
          label: "small",
          stock: 5,
          price: 3,
        },
        {
          label: "medium",
          stock: 5,
          price: 3,
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

when a new item comes in, I want to insert a new document to `items`, unless an item exists with the same `type` and `color` as the new one, in this case I want only to merge `sizes` into that existing `item`'s `sizes`.

`sizes` does *not* have to be unique.

I tried to use `$push` with `upsert: true` and `arrayFilters` but apparently `$push` ignores `arrayFilters`.

`node` with `mongodb` package.

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- filter to see if exists
- if exists map to update, else add in the end

*2 array reads, but stil faster than query2

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/brwilhwnccg)

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "newitem": {
        "type": "shirt",
        "color": "red",
        "sizes": [
          {
            "label": "medium"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "found": {
        "$ne": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$items",
              "cond": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.type",
                      "$newitem.type"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.color",
                      "$newitem.color"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "items": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$not": [
              "$found"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$items",
              [
                "$newitem"
              ]
            ]
          },
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$items",
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$and": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$$this.type",
                          "$newitem.type"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$$this.color",
                          "$newitem.color"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        "sizes": {
                          "$concatArrays": [
                            "$$this.sizes",
                            "$newitem.sizes"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "found",
      "newitem"
    ]
  }
])
```

Query2
(alternative solution)

- reduce and do the update
- if found keep the updated, else add in the end

*1 array read (but concat is slow, for big arrays, >500 members, if you have big arrays use query1)

*this is the normal way to do it, if we had a fast way to add in the end of the array, but we dont, so Query1 is faster

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sZ_-hfNFSi5)

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "newitem": {
        "type": "shirt",
        "color": "red",
        "sizes": [
          {
            "label": "medium"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "items-found": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$items",
          "initialValue": {
            "items": [],
            "found": null
          },
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$value.found",
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.type",
                      "$newitem.type"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$this.color",
                      "$newitem.color"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "items": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$$value.items",
                    [
                      {
                        "$mergeObjects": [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            "sizes": {
                              "$concatArrays": [
                                "$$this.sizes",
                                "$newitem.sizes"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "found": true
              },
              {
                "items": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$$value.items",
                    [
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "found": "$$value.found"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "items": {
        "$cond": [
          "$items-found.found",
          "$items-found.items",
          {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$items-found.items",
              [
                "$newitem"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "items-found",
      "newitem"
    ]
  }
])
```